# perl find and replace with single quotes

Tags: perl

I need to find / replace the following string in all the .txt files in my working directory:

```
myfunc(l_define,'BASE TABLE')
```

I've tried the following, which runs without errors, but doesn't update the file(s).

```
perl -pi -w -e "s/myfunc(l_define,'BASE')/myfunc(l_define,'BASE',1,1,'')/g;" *.txt
```

Is it a quoting issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a regex, what's between `(` and `)` is a capture group.

So for the `(` or `)` characters you need to escape them, so that the literal characters are matched.  So use `\(` and `\)` in the regex.

Hence, a regex like `func(akes)` would only match `funcakes`.

Escaping is often needed to match characters that have a special meaning in the regex syntax:
 `. ( ) [ ] + * ? { } ^ $ \ |`
Also `/` if the code uses something like `s/a\/b/a-b/g` instead of something like `s@a/b@a-b@g`

And if you really don't like to use those backslashes?
You could also use a character class: `[(]` and `[)]`